# Replicate featured image functionality

Tags: post-thumbnails, media-library

Is there a wordpress way of creating a custom field just like the [Featured Image](https://support.wordpress.com/featured-images/) field?

The field should be implemented in my custom meta box on the post edit page at the back-end.

Comment: There's a plugin for this that works so well that I've never bothered coding this myself. Multi Post Thumbnails.

Comment: If you're looking for help with code then please do review [ask] and post your first attempts to code this.

Comment: @AndyMacaulay-Brook There are lots of plugins what are able to do this, for example Advanced Custom Fields. But I don't want to be depended on those plugins. That's why I'm asking for "a wordpress way" to achieve this, something like `media_handle_upload()` but then for media library browser as well. As of now I couldn't find a method what fulfills these features, that's why I ask this question.